# What is computational complexity of $Ax=b$ when size of A increasing

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, computational-complexity

I have a linear equation

$$Ax=b$$

where $A$ is non-singular matrix $N \times N$, $x,b$ are vector $N\times 1$, $A,b$ are given and I want to find $x$

It is clear that $x$ can find by $x=A^{-1}b$. I would like to know how computational complexity increasing when $N$ is increasing (you can use any method to find solution)? Thank you in advance

Comment: Actually, I use MATLAB for measuring the time consuming. I use code as x=A\b. The code will chose a best algorithm to find solution. Hence, the method does not matter in here. You can chose any method to analysis.

Comment: The (worst case) computational complexity to get exact solutions is $O(N^3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact methods for a $n \times n$ matrix need at least $n^2$ steps, the present theoretical boundary seems to be $O(n^{2.376})$ ([source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineares_Gleichungssystem#L.C3.B6sungsverfahren)). Gauss elimination needs $O(n^3)$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computational_efficiency)).

There are approximative methods, like Gauss-Seidel which are faster.

And there are methods which have advantages for certain matrices.

Comment: Thank mvw. It means that the complexity grows as $N^3$ when $N$ increasing. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, which is growing fast, if you e.g. perform a larger FEM calculation. That is why approximative methods are used there.

Comment: Does the complexity become any better for the special case of $b= 0$? I.e. what is the computational complexity of determining the kernel of an $n \times n$ real matrix?